# Using `--as-needed` but `ldd -u -r` still reports unused direct dependencies

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, ldd

For one of my binaries CMake produces cmdline that looks like this:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++  
-O3 -DNDEBUG   
-s 
-Wl,--as-needed 
-Wl,--gc-sections 
<blah-blah>.o
...
-o procmon.e 
-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64
<my lib>.a
...
/usr/local/lib64/libxalan-c.so 
/usr/local/lib64/libxerces-c.so
/home/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libcurl.a 
...
-lcrypt 
<more vcpkg static libs>
-lrt 
-lpthread 
<more vcpkg static libs>
-lm 
<more vcpkg static libs>
-ldl 
<more vcpkg static libs>
-pthread 
<more vcpkg static libs>
```

As you see `--as-needed` is specified and yet I still end up with unused dependencies:

```
$ ldd -u -r procmon.e
Unused direct dependencies:
        /usr/local/lib64/libxalan-c.so.111
        /lib64/libcrypt.so.1
        /lib64/libm.so.6
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--as-needed` works during linking stage by ignoring a shared library (currently being processed) if it didn't resolve any **currently** unknown symbols. Garbage collection of sections (`--gc-sections`) kicks in after this and it can result in removal of all symbols references that were (on previous step) resolved with given shared lib, causing behavior mentioned in original post.

[Here is](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24836) some additional reading.